# How to show all the fields of a maintenance view

Tags: abap

I am trying to extend the maintenance view(sm30) of a table, so that all the fields of a table are shown without paging. So the current look is:
[image]

Now I need to show all the fields of the table without scrolling to the right. Does anyone know how is this done?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The screen (dynpro) has to be resized. This can be done manually in SE11, menü maintenance view and there is a field for the screen number, double click, change manually and and activate.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @Philipp lack of time to post a proper answer with screenshots, sorry, you can post it

Comment: The author of the question is the best placed to take the screenshots and post the answer with all the details, it will make the question and answer more coherent!

Comment: I recorded a couple of screen shots for followers wondering about how to best fix their generated screen., since Jozef didnt want to.

Answer (score 3):

The Table maintenance generator has a number of annoying weaknesses.
Generating overview lists with a width of 80 is most obvious one.
So if you are generating maintenance views for your own tables, it is easily improved.

1. Generate your maintenance screen .
   [image: Typical overview table header]
2. Drill down to the generated dynpro.
   [image: System Status]
   [image: Screen attributes]

You will notice on the screen attributes it is only 83 byte wide !!!! WHY ???
That goes all the way back R/3 version 2.x in the early to mid 90s.

So just make the width 250 chars.
Then goto Layout.
Grab the lower corner and drag out to 250 char wide.
[image: Drag bottom right corner to desired width]

when you are done, the occupied width will reflect the change
[image: screen attributes]

Now activate.

The next time you use the overview screen you will see 250 chars of table.

I often adjust the width of some fields while doing this in the case they are
are unnecessarily large.

EDIT: NOTE about regeneration.
If you regenerate your screen/s , you will need to redo the changes.

Comment: You might want to add a warning that regenerating the dynpros from SM54 will revert any manual changes you made, and you have to redo them in those cases.